# How to cull the backside of a mesh but keep the lights inside?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, shaders, lighting

First off: the "backface culling" option for materials doesn't seem to do anything.

Second: I got the effect I wanted (almost) by using the Geometry node to mix a Transparent shader with a Principled BSDF using Backfacing as the Factor:

[image]

I need to keep the lights inside the rooms "trapped". The light should not be escaping like it is. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your picture, lights look like point. try with out lights and change the color of cubes:
picture 1
[image]

secondly, add black ground with a material with many roughness: picture 2

[image]

And play with cube's nodes

according to me it's the only solution.

Comment: That is one idea if you want to bake the light, but I am looking for a solution that constricts light. One thing I figured out was duping the mesh for the rooms, scaling it outward slightly, and marking it invisible to the camera (Object Properties -> Ray Visibility). I have done this in Unity before but was hoping for another solution because tweaking the geometry is very fiddly. This works, it's just hard to scale (as in "scalable solution")